# Pusher\Exception\HttpException Bad request

Tags: pusher, laravel-5.6

laravel- 5.6
Php - 7.2
pusher - 3.0

when try to connect with pusher:
[image: when try to connect with pusher]

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: want to create real time chat app

Answer (score 2):

You should provide more details to your question so others have a better picture of what might cause the problem.

But I ran into the exact same problem recently and might be able to help. In my instance, this problem is caused by composer pulling in pusher dev-lib instead of published version when I run `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"`. It happens because I don't have `php-curl` installed in my setup. After installing it, I remove the current dev-lib, rerun `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server "~3.0"` and it works like a charm.

Comment: It actually solved my issue as I had the same scenario and reinstalling the pusher-php-server from vagrant fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

1. run command below ON UBUNTU SERVER 18.4

   `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php`
2. install curl for php (php7.2 is php version)

   `sudo apt install php7.2-curl`      (php7.2 is php version)
3. update pusher server run it in laravel project

   `composer require pusher/pusher-php-server`
4. Restart NGINX service

   `service nginx restart`

It works for me.