# Bad Request on sending Pusher Requests

Tags: laravel-5

I'm getting 400 Bad Request when pushing an event. But the request is updated in the pusher dashboard.

This is the same issue reported in [This Ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49003306/pusher-exception-httpexception-bad-request), but it didn't solve my problem so far.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve my problem. Basically what I did is update composer again. The version of vender files do a massive part in the Laravel application.